# Template function with std::async in clang

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, libstdc++

I was looking at the example for `std::async` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>

template <typename RAIter>
int parallel_sum(RAIter beg, RAIter end)
{
    auto len = std::distance(beg, end);
    if(len < 1000)
        return std::accumulate(beg, end, 0);

    RAIter mid = beg + len/2;
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async,
                              parallel_sum<RAIter>, mid, end);
    int sum = parallel_sum(beg, mid);
    return sum + handle.get();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10000, 1);
    std::cout << "The sum is " << parallel_sum(v.begin(), v.end()) << '\n';
}
```

I tried compiling it with the web compiler for Clang 3.4 and it resulted in the output `The sum is` instead of the expected `The sum is 1000`.

I copied the example and compiled with clang 3.5-1ubuntu1 / gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit using the following command:

```
clang++ -g main.cpp -std=c++1y -o out -pthread;
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:15:19: error: no matching function for call to 'async'

    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async,
                  ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:24:35: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'parallel_sum<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
      > >' requested here
    std::cout << "The sum is " << parallel_sum(v.begin(), v.end()) << '\n';
                                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/future:1523:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fn = int
      (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >), _Args =
      <__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &>]:
      function cannot return function type 'int (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *,
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)'
    async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/future:1543:5: note: 
      candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fn = std::launch, _Args = <int
      (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >),
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &>]: no
      type named 'type' in 'std::result_of<std::launch (int
      (*)(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >),
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &,
      __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int *, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > &)>'
    async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
    ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Is this a bug in clang, gcc, libstdc++, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hm. The culprit is here: `with _Fn = int (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<..>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<..>)` This should be an lvalue-reference. Seems there's a problem with deduction.

Comment: OK, I've boiled it down to the following issue: `template<class T> void deduce(T&&) { /* print type T */ }`. for `deduce(parallel_sum<int*>);`, clang++ deduces `T == int(int*,int*)` whereas g++ deduces `T == int(&)(int*,int*)`. This causes the problem.

Comment: This looks very much like a clang++ bug. If the function is not a function template specialization, it deduces an lvalue reference. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0431fb448b1f1776)

Comment: As a workaround, clang does compile if the argument to `async` is `static_cast<decltype((parallel_sum<RAIter>))>(parallel_sum)` :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in clang++. Unless there's a strange restricted rule that I'm not aware of, an id-expression referring to a function is an lvalue. However, clang++ makes a distinction between function template specializations and ordinary functions in the deduction for a universal reference:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void print_type()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

template <class T>
int foo(bool) { return 42; }

int bar(bool) { return 42; }

template<class T>
void deduce(T&&)
{
    print_type<T>();
}

int main()
{
    deduce(foo<bool>);
    deduce(bar);
}
```

Output, clang++ up to and including an early 3.5:

```
void print_type() [T = int (bool)]
void print_type() [T = int (&)(bool)]
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26a923d4191430f0)

---

`std::result_of` is used in libstdc++'s implementation of `std::async` to get the return type of the function ([snippet from here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1ac4f98fb049196384f95808bb5ee47b33de9ad0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/future)):

```
template<typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
future<typename result_of<_Fn(_Args...)>::type>
async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
```

If we pass `foo<bool>` as the second argument, clang++ deduces `_Fn == int (bool)`.

The type of the function (object) is combined with the argument types for `result_of`. This is probably a relict of C++03, where we didn't have variadic templates yet. The argument types are passed to allow `result_of` to resolve overloaded functions like an overloaded `operator()` in case `_Fn` is a class type.

However, if `_Fn` is deduced not to a function reference, but to a function type, the combination `_Fn(_Args...)` forms an illegal type: a function returning a function:

```
     _Fn           == int(bool)
     _Args...      == bool
==>  _Fn(_Args...) == int(bool)(bool)
```

---

But there's more to it: The above declaration of `async` is defective, see [LWG 2021](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2021). [Howard Hinnant changed the declaration in **libc++**](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/0836f87fb94d2d2bcf01b6541bd41e92e27d6181) to:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
future < typename result_of<
             typename decay<F>::type(typename decay<Args>::type...)
         >::type
       >
async(launch policy, F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

so libc++ decays the function to a function pointer. The problem caused by the missing lvalue reference disappears.